# Twitter authentication for a user using Parse server and JS client side

Tags: javascript, authentication, twitter, parse-platform

Good evening,

I've spent several hours by now searching for a way to implement 'Log In with Twitter' functionality to my application that uses Parse back-end service and Javascript client side. I implemented Facebook authentication but I can't find a proper tutorial how to do the same with twitter. Has anyone ever tried to achieve that? I'd like to get some hints as I am new to parse.

As far as I understand, I need to send a post request to one of twitter's urls with certain keys that I have set when initializing parse server and twitter should generate a token. I am not quite sure how to do that the right way and how to create a Parse.User() upon a success response from twitter.

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/android-twitter-login

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention. I am using javascript as my front end so I do not have access to TwitterUtils. @DaviMacêdo

Comment: This guide may help you with JS: https://www.back4app.com/docs/javascript/login-twitter